# How to store a one to many relation in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

I'm making a website and I need to store a random number of data in my database.

For example, User john may have one phone number where jack can have 3.

I need to be able to store an infinite number of values per user.

Comment: This is just a one to many relationship. E.g a user can have many phone numbers. This will be covered in a database concepts tutorial somewhere.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You create a separate table for phone numbers (i.e. a 1:M relationship).

```
create table `users` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(`id`)
);

create table `phone_numbers` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `user_id` int unsigned not null,
  `phone_number` varchar(25) not null,
  index pn_user_index(`user_id`),
  foreign key (`user_id`) references users(`id`) on delete cascade,
  primary key(`id`)
);
```

Now you can, in an easily manner, get a users phone numbers with a simple join;

```
select
  pn.`phone_number`
from
  `users` as u,
  `phone_numbers` as pn
where
  u.`name`='John'
  and
  pn.`user_id`=u.`id`
```

Comment: Regarding the 2nd table, is the phone_numbers.id field necessary? Would it be ok to do `update phone_numbers where user_id = '12345' AND phone_number = '123-456-7890'` I want to do this correctly, but I'm trying to understand why the phone_numbers.id field is needed. Thank you!

Comment: @cmpreshn - I wouldn't say it's necessary, depending on your project of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a one to many relationship table.

You can see more infos here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html