# How would this get stored in a database?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, django, sqlite

Ok so I have a name, a time/data, and an array...

so in my database I store in the table, the:

name, time/data, but the array?

This array doesn't have a fixed size... It is an array of tuples (x,y) <- even thats an array

I want to associate the name and time/date with this array. I heard its not good and impossible to store an array in a database, I'm using sqllite3..

How do I solve this problem? Do I just let the name and timedate table point to a newly constructed table for the array?

Comment: You would probably want to use another table then do a join. Its called a 1 to many relationship. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402422/how-to-store-a-one-to-many-relation-in-my-sql-database-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a table with X, Y, timestamp and a foreignkey to an entry in an entry table.

Data table:

```
ID  | Index |  X  |  Y  |  EntryID
0   |   0   | 3.2 | 4.3 |   1
1   |   1   | 2.1 | 1.2 |   1
........
n-1 |   n-1 | xn  | yn  |   1

# The above is from array 1, below from another array

n   |   0   | 2.2 | 2.4 |   2
n+1 |   1   | 2.1 | 1.9 |   2
.........
n+m-1 | m-1 | xm  | ym  |   2
```

Entry table:

```
ID | Name          | DateTime
1  | user3043594   | 2013-..
2  | Steinar Lima  | 2012-..
```

You store all entries from all arrays in this table, and filter them based on entry id. Then you can do a join to get the user name from the user table.

Comment: wait, I think you missed it! It is an array of ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)... (xn,yn)). Do you mind making an edit for that?

Comment: No, just save all tuples as a row in this table. So X1 goes in column X in row 1, Y1 in column Y in row 1.. etc. You may want to add an index column to the table, to keep track of the index in the array. I'll update my answer.

Comment: wait. its like this name, date time, ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)... (xn,yn)).. Don't I want to link it to another table with a row thats n long? or is this the one to many thing someone else mentioned?

Comment: With my solution you would have to repeat DateTime for each row, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Given that you don't understand the concept of one to many relationships, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Thank you Dan Bracuk! Thank you Steinar Lima!