# how can i design one to many database relationship for a notification system tables?

Tags: mysql, notifications

I'm working on  a notification system for a website and here's the basic idea;
I have a table `Notifications` where I have columns

> **notif_msg**     **notif_url**      **receiver_s**

where `receiver_s` will have multiple commas separated values. However, I learned this is not so good idea and was advised to have a different table to store receivers. creating a one to many relationships as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402422/how-to-store-a-one-to-many-relation-in-my-sql-database-mysql). However, I am baffled on few things as I am no guru in MySQL.
here's how my create statement looks like following the example from the link above;

```
create table `notifications` ( `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,`notif_msg` varchar(500) not null,`notif_url` varchar(100) not null, primary key(`id`));
create table `notifications_target` ( `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment, `notification_id` int unsigned not null, `receiver` varchar(25) not null, index pn_user_index(`notification_id`), foreign key (`notification_id`) references notifications(`id`) on delete cascade,primary key(`id`));
```

I need to know a few things;

1. what function does the `index` serve in there?
2. from here, how do I insert value into `notif_msg`, `notif_url` in `notifications` table and multiple receivers into `receivers` column in `notification_target` referencing a particular row in `notifications` table?
3. How do I get values back from `notifications` table and their corresponding `receiver` in `notification_target` table?

here's how I intend to get `notifications` relating to a specific user and all users at the same time before now;

> SELECT `notif_msg`, `notif_url` FROM `notifications` WHERE receiver_s= somename AND WHERE receiver_s=' '

how do I do this now that I have different tables for receivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.what function does the index serve in there?

Read below for more information about indexes in MySQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html

> 2. from here, how do I insert value into notif_msg, notif_url in notifications table and multiple receivers into receivers column in
>      notification_target referencing a particular row in notifications
>      table?
> 3. How do I get values back from notifications table and their corresponding receiver in notification_target table?

When u created a one to many mapping, this is the structure you are looking at :
[image: One to many]

So basically your `id` is helping you map the rows in another table as `notification_id`

So to answer your questions :

2. When you insert rows in second table, make sure their `notification_id` (which is the foreign key) is same as the `id` in the main table
3. When you select rows from second table, add a condition on `notification_id` if you want to fetch records for a given `id`, or use `join` query to fetch results.

---

For your specific case : refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47d29/4

Your tables :

```
create table `notifications` ( `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,`notif_msg` varchar(500) not null,`notif_url` varchar(100) not null, primary key(`id`));
create table `notifications_target` ( `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment, `notification_id` int unsigned not null, `receiver` varchar(25) not null, index pn_user_index(`notification_id`), foreign key (`notification_id`) references notifications(`id`) on delete cascade,primary key(`id`));
```

Data :

```
insert into notifications values (1, 'Hello', '../welcome.html'); 
insert into notifications_target(`notification_id`, `receiver`) values (1, 'Jack'); 
insert into notifications_target(`notification_id`, `receiver`) values (1, 'Marry'); 
insert into notifications_target(`notification_id`, `receiver`) values (1, 'User'); 


insert into notifications values (2, 'Good bye', '../logout.html'); 
insert into notifications_target(`notification_id`, `receiver`) values (2, 'Jack');
```

Notice that : `notification_id` in `notifications_target` table is same as the `id` in `notifications` table.

And to fetch records :

Will fetch all the notifications for all the users :

```
select t1.notif_msg, t1.notif_url, t2.receiver
from notifications t1 inner join notifications_target t2 
on t1.id = t2.notification_id;
```

Will fetch all the notifications for specific user :

```
select t1.notif_msg, t1.notif_url, t2.receiver
from notifications t1 inner join notifications_target t2 
on t1.id = t2.notification_id
where t2.receiver = 'Jack';
```

Comment: now im getting it. we insert values into notifications and save the id in notification_id field. awesome.

Comment: It is making the query faster. Have a look at the link i have added in the answer to understand how it works.